# How to mix columns in a Bootstrap responsive website without breaking the desktop version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website with Bootstrap and I'm facing a responsivity problem

[image: Example]

I want that grid 1 become mobile 2, basically.

But if I develop mobile 2, i get grid 2 which is bad. If I develop grid 1, I get mobile 1 which is also bad, because I want to mix sidebar elements into my mobile version without breaking my columns

Is it possible to solve this without forcing it badly with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible without JS. Take a look at the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) lib.

Comment: Masonry seems great, but a I need to use Bootstrap

Comment: you can combine both.

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos: Are you sure? Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/r46pe5s6/

Answer (score 0):

#### Working bootply

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">5</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">6</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">4</div>
```

CSS used for demo:

```
div{
    border:1px solid;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS media query to pull the taller columns to the right on wider screen widths (ie; greater that 768 pixels)..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .tall {
      float:right;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/Zkloc3WAtV