# Responsive div order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to the bootstrap grid system, and I want to reorder the `<div>` regions for mobiles.

This is the layout I have for the desktop view:

[image: current column layout]

And this is what I want for mobile phones:

[image: resized column layout]

My current HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="A">  A  </div>
  <div id="B">  B  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
  C
</div>
```

Currently, if I view the page on a mobile phone the order is A->B->C because A & B are both inside the first column. But I don't know how to achieve the A->C->B order. So how do I do this?

Comment: You may want to consider using javascript & media queries in order to reorder the dom elements at smaller screen resolutions.... I am currently looking into bootstrap documentation to see if it can provide said functionality

Comment: Media Query is a good way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mix columns in a Bootstrap responsive website without breaking the desktop version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540716/how-to-mix-columns-in-a-bootstrap-responsive-website-without-breaking-the-deskto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't the most elegant way to go about it, but you could just hide element B when switching to mobile and show a different element B with the same content that's below element C in the dom by using bootstrap's "hidden-xs" and "visible-xs" classes. Something like this...

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
       <div id="A">  A  </div>
       <div id="B" class="hidden-xs">  B  </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
       C
     </div>
     <div id="B" class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">  B  </div>
</div>
```

I'd also recommend referring to the the [official bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more info

Comment: It's indeed not really elegant, but it will do.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `md` in `col-md-9` stands for medum devices, which means all devices with a screen resulution up to 992px.

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) you will find a table with `col-xs`, `col-sm`. `col-md` and `col-lg` resultions.

You can use them to define `col-xs-12` to your elements. This will tell the browser that on devices which apply to the `xs` definition the column takes all the 12 grid parts. You can apply several rules like for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">foo</div>
```

This means the element is 12 on `xs` and 6 on `md` devices.

Comment: You should reread the question. That does not answer it at all, he needs to adjust the order of dom elements, his code works fine for switching to mobile...